# Split in Regex Python Infix Notation in Numerical Expressions

Tags: python, regex

I want to write a Python script where the user can input like that:

```
input1 = "12/(2+4)*21**2"
input2 = "12,/,(,2,+,4,),*,21,**,2"
input3 = "12 / ( 2 + 4 ) * 21 ** 2"
```

The output should always be such that:

```
output = ["12", "/", "(", "2", "+", "4", ")", "*", "21", "**", "2"]
```

What I have been doing is:

```
re.sub("([/+*](**))", r" \1 ", expression).split()
```

But it does not work and I am not super familiar with regex. Can anyone help out?

Comment: Your question needs a bit more detail about what specifically you want to acheive. Could you write the rules that you want to enforce using regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using an alternation:

```py
>>> re.findall(r"\d+|\*+|[-+/()]", input1)
['12', '/', '(', '2', '+', '4', ')', '*', '21', '**', '2']
>>> re.findall(r"\d+|\*+|[-+/()]", input2)
['12', '/', '(', '2', '+', '4', ')', '*', '21', '**', '2']
>>> re.findall(r"\d+|\*+|[-+/()]", input3)
['12', '/', '(', '2', '+', '4', ')', '*', '21', '**', '2']
```

Comment: Considering that you not being asked to check the string for mathematically correctness (e.g., `[ "(", "1", "2", "("]`) would be returned for `"(1 2("`), you could replace `[-+/()]` with `[^, ]`.